# Automatic authentication in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, authentication, phpmyadmin

I have a local phpMyAdmin (installed via apt-get) adn I'm tired of entering login and password every time I try to open it. Database contains no sensitive info, just test tables, and is visible only from 127.0.0.1

I want phpMyAdmin already be logged in as `root` user with password `1234` (for example) when I open it. How do I do that?

P.S. Saving password in a browser is not what I want.

**SOLUTION:**

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '1234'; // use here your password
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
```

Answer (score 0):

In config.inc.php, you can also find these lines around line 94 where you can just uncomment the line:

```
/* Uncomment the following to enable logging in to passwordless accounts,
 * after taking note of the associated security risks. */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

This is easier than changing `auth_type` in the file and settign the username and password.